# Unable to get the ActionBar ID using AppCompat Activity

Tags: android, mobile

Unable to get the id with the below code when updated to AppCompatActivity.

```
int abContainerViewID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
return (FrameLayout) ((AppCompatActivity) context).findViewById(abContainerViewID);
```

The above method is returning Null now.

This is my App Theme

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get ActionBar like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am looking for the container ID of the actionbar in support lib which is a FrameLayout.